# How do I check if a cell is blank for Conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In my exercise tracking spreadsheet, I want blank cells in columns `B:O` highlighted if column `A` is today's date, and the cell itself is blank. I have tried this:

`=AND(ISBLANK(B3),$A:A=INT(NOW()))` applied to range `B3:O1000`, but it doesn't highlight anything. [Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yo1hEXNkLDYv9VJ6oScaK0UyxbXW2CiRsFq4QsqH2Xs/edit?usp=sharing) For the second term of the `AND()`, I've tried `A:A=INT(NOW()),$A3=INT(NOW())`, `INT(NOW()), $A:$A=INT(NOW())` and `A3=INT(NOW())`, all with the same result: formatting not applied.

In column `A`, the formula `=A:A=int(now())` *does* apply the intended format. If to the larger range, I just apply `=ISBLANK(B3)` without checking the date, all the blank cells are formatted. If I put the `AND` formula into a cell with references to today's date in column `A` and any blank cell, it returns `TRUE`. Confused!

OUCH!

JPV's answer solved the problem perfectly - yesterday. Today, with the new conditional formatting custom formula unchanged, it's back.

Blank cells in today's row aren't formatted in Safari (7.1.3 (9537.85.12.18), Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.89) or Firefox 36.0.1. I'm using a MacBook Air 13", OS X 10.9.5 4GB RAM, 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5.

I'm tempted to think Google has a server-side problem, because some of my earlier unsuccessful efforts *did* show the intended formatting on my iOS 7 iPhone - sometimes.

Can anyone explain or duplicate this problem?

Answer (score 3):

With the range set to:  B3:O1000

Try:

```
=AND(ISBLANK(B3),INT($A3)=INT(today()))
```

or even shorter:

```
=AND(ISBLANK(B3),$A3=today())
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a million. Don't know why I didn't try $A3.